# cswtch generation in gcc c compiler

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I have a doubt about object code generation in the gcc compiler.

In my program, objdump shows that `CSWTCH` sections are generated.

1. Could you explain what criteria in C code require `CSWTCH` sections
   to be generated?
2. Will the assigned output section for the `CSWTCH` section be in `.rodata`.
3. Under which condition will small rodata be assigned as an output section for `CSWTCH`.

Comment: From what I gather from [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49857) they are generated when the compiler decides to map a `switch` statement to a lookup table and they end up in `.data`.

Comment: You have a *question*, not a *doubt* :-) see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers are (1) there are no such criteria: this is just one compiler's technique for generating a value table; (2) that's up to the compiler, assembler, and linker; and (3) that's up to the compiler, assembler, and linker.

GCC (at least gcc version 5) emits both `.section` and `.type` directives here on x86:

```
$ cat cswitch.c
int sw_2 (char x)
{
    switch(x) 
    { 
        case '0': return -1;
        case '1': return  2;
        case '2': return  3;
        case '3': return  5;
        case '4': return  7;
        case '5': return 11;
        case '6': return 13;
        case '7': return 17;
        case '8': return 19;
        case '9': return 23;
        case 'a':return 29;
        case 'A':return 29;
    }

    return -1;
}
$ gcc -Os -S cswitch.c
$ cat cswitch.s
        .file   "cswitch.c"
[mass snippage]
        .section        .rodata
        .align 32
        .type   CSWTCH.1, @object
        .size   CSWTCH.1, 49
CSWTCH.1:
```

(I found that the `-Os` switch is required to produce the lookup table on x86.  With `-O`, I get a more typical jump table.)

In this case, the `.section` directive ends up applying and putting the table into the `.rodata` section.  But this is just one system's method of implementation—there is no hard and fast requirement on the compiler.

Note that you can make a source transformation that is *likely* to get the compiler to emit the table in a read-only-data-section:

```
int sw_3(char x)
{
    const char table['a' - '1'] = {
        '1' - '1': 2,
        '2' - '1': 3,
        '3' - '1': 5,
        /* ... fill in the remainder as needed */
    };
    if (x >= '1' && x <= 'A') return table[x - '1'];
    return -1;
}
```

(This transformation assumes that the system uses ASCII or UTF-8 or similar.)  However, even here, a compiler is allowed to generate any arbitrary machine code as long as it produces the results required by whatever standards apply.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. i got problem in one of my source code.well i have object code only. i can see lookup table is generated.but .section applied to this lookup table is .srodata.  so i am trying to find  how .srodata is applied to those .section. also in above example instead of predefined characters in case statements if some const variable are used. then there could be chance of .srodata. please correct me if above statements are not clear

Comment: In GNU linker scripts, you can capture any section you like and treat it any way you like. An `.srodata` section is intended as "small read-only data": the usual idea is to collect all the small sections together and set them up to be addressed with short-offset addressing instructions, so you should write a linker script that does that (or use a provided one that does that).